# Validating an image file in Javascript (more than just extension or MIME type)

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am currently validating that I have an image file in Javascript using

```
file.type.match(/image.*/)
```

but this is letting through files that are malformed enough not to work in some browsers. For example, [a jpg](http://dev.gosizzle.io/uploads/32_180_1457648809963_Interana.jpg) was uploaded that displays fine in Chrome but shows up as malformed in Firefox & Safari (haven't tested IE or Edge yet). I know I can do a more thorough validation in PHP with

```
exif_imagetype($filepath)
```

but I wondering if there was a more robust way than `match` to do it in Javascript.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on javascript to validate anything that's not re-validated later by **your** server.

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra Good advice ... but somewhat irrelevant to the question if I'm running a Node server.

Comment: When you say malformed, are we talking about full on broken (not displaying) or corrupt-but-visible in some form?

Comment: Could be useful: https://stereochro.me/ideas/detecting-broken-images-js

Comment: @DBS The image (see link to it in post above) displays fine in Chrome, but just comes up with the broken image icon in the other browsers.

Comment: I looked at image validation online, looks like the problem is [No color-space metadata and no embedded color profile](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.gosizzle.io%2Fuploads%2F32_180_1457648809963_Interana.jpg)

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra Now that is a handy tool!